# autosummary “toctree contains reference to nonexisting document” warnings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc

I am facing the same problem as in this [thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4qv.png). When I build my Sphinx documentation with `make html` then I get a lot of warnings like this

```sh
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'cars.Car.time_elapsed'
```

I am using `html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'`. If I change it to `classic`, then I don't get the warnings. If I add `numpydoc_show_class_members = False` to `conf.py`, then I don't get them either.

BUT; I really like `sphinx_rtd_theme` and when I use `classic` or add `numpydoc_show_class_members = False`, then a '*TOC*' of my Python methods are removed, which I prefer staying (see the red box in the image) .

[image]

The documentation of the `cars` module is made by

```
.. automodule:: cars
   :members:
```

The module contains a single class `Car` with two methods. The docstrings are written in `numpydoc`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are currently using the `numpydoc` extension. Please note that Numpy and Google style docstrings are now supported by the builtin `sphinx.ext.napoleon` extension.

Removing the `numpydoc` extension and using `sphinx.ext.napoleon` will likely solve your problem.

---

#### Sources

- [Napoleon - Marching toward legible docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest)
- [Sphinx Doc - Support for NumPy and Google style docstrings](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html)